# クラスのメソッドに関数を代入する処理が上書きなのかプロパティを作成しているのか知りたい

Tags: javascript

以下のようなクラスに`foo`というメソッドがあり、`hasOwnProperty`で`foo`がプロパティでないことを確認しました。

```
class Hoge {
  foo() {
    console.log('元の foo');
  }
}
const hoge = new Hoge();
hoge.foo(); // => '元の foo'
console.log(hoge.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // => false（foo はメソッド）
```

次に`foo`に対して無名関数を代入しました。
確認してみると今度は`foo`がプロパティになっています。

```
// foo に関数を代入
hoge.foo = () => {
  console.log('上書きした foo');
};
hoge.foo(); // => '上書きした foo'
console.log(hoge.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // => true（foo はプロパティ）
```

今度は上書きした `foo` を `delete`で削除してみます。
削除した後実行してみると元の foo に戻っています。

```
// foo を削除
delete hoge.foo;
hoge.foo(); // => '元の foo'
```

ここまで「上書き」と書いてきたのですが、`foo`に関数を代入して上書きしたはずなのに、`delete`で削除しても元のメソッドが残っているところから、もしかしたらこれは上書きではなく「メソッドとは別物の同名のプロパティを作成している」のかもしれないと疑問に思いました。（delete 演算子が削除するのはプロパティなので）

長々と分かりにくい質問をすみません。
結局何が言いたいかといいますと、下記の部分が

1. foo メソッドを上書きしている
2. foo メソッドとは全く別物の同名の foo プロパティを新たに作成している

のどちらが正しいのでしょうかという質問になります。

```
// 上書き？ or プロパティを新規作成？
hoge.foo = () => {
  // 処理
};
```

詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[独自プロパティ (own property)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes#%E7%8B%AC%E8%87%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%91%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3) かどうかを意識すると理解しやすいと思います。

あるオブジェクトのプロパティにアクセスするとき、独自プロパティが存在すればそれが参照され、そうでなければそのオブジェクトのプロトタイプのプロパティを探します。`class` 構文を用いた場合、メソッドはプロトタイプのプロパティとして格納され、それ以外のプロパティはインスタンスの独自プロパティになります。
プロトタイプにあるメソッドと同じ名前の独自プロパティがあると、プロトタイプにあるメソッドは隠れてしまうわけです。

Comment: なるほど、ということは`hoge.foo`に関数を代入する部分は、メソッド（プロトタイプのプロパティ）を上書きではなく、「インスタンスの独自プロパティ」を新規作成していて、`delete`で削除されるのはインスタンスの方だけで、削除後に隠れていたメソッド（プロトタイプのプロパティ）が姿を現すということだったのですね。
とても勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

> 2. foo メソッドとは全く別物の同名の foo プロパティを新たに作成している

こちらの解釈でほぼ問題ありません。

質問に書いてあった

```
class Fuga {
  bar = 'これはプロパティ';
  bar() {
    console.log('これはメソッド');
  }
}
const fuga = new Fuga();
```

の`fuga`が`hoge`と同じようになっているという解釈も正しいです。実情を表していますし、[パブリッククラスフィールド](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)を使ったとてもわかりやすいコードだと思います。`bar`が上書きれたのでは無く、オブジェクトが持つプロパティによって隠されたというのが最も正確な表現でしょう。

---

以下、細かい話です。ちょっと難しいので、興味がある人だけ読んでください。

`hoge.bar`と`hoge.bar = ...`では`bar`がどのプロパティになるのかですが、その処理は似ているようで結構な違いがあります。前者の処理をゲット、後者の処理をセット、`hoge`をレシーバー、`bar`をプロパティの名前として解説します。なお、一部特殊なオブジェクト(エキゾティックオブジェクトといわれるもの)では動作の細部が異なることがありますが、今回は一般的なオブジェクト(オーティナリーオブジェクト)を前提とします。

ゲットの処理は単純です。その名前のプロパティが現れるまで、プロトタイプチェーンを辿ります。少し注意すべきなのは、プロパティが値では無くゲッター(`get`を使って定義するプロパティ)の関数になっている場合は、レシーバーに対してその関数を呼び出すと言うことです。

セットの処理も、実のところはプロトタイプチェーンを辿ります。辿り着いた先のプロパティが値なのか、セッターの関数なのか、値であっても書き込み可能かによって異なります。

1. プロパティが値である(valueを持つ)、かつ、書き込み可能(writableが真)な場合 ... レシーバーに対して、その名前のプロパティに右辺値が入ります。(プロパティの操作をするのは、プロトタイプチェーンを辿って見つけたプロパティを持つオブジェクトではなく、辿るときの大本であったレシーバーであることに注意してください。)
2. プロパティが値である(valueを持つ)、かつ、書き込み不可(writableが偽)な場合 ... 処理が失敗となり、 **プロパティは何も変更されません。**
3. プロパティが値でない(valueをもたず、getやsetを持つ)場合 ...レシーバーに対して(thisがレシーバーになると言うこと)、setにある関数(`set`を使って定義するセッターのこと)を右辺値を引数として呼び出します。(setがない場合は、失敗になります。この動作はgetの場合とほぼ同じです。)
4. プロパティが見つからなかった場合 ... レシーバーに対して、その名前のプロパティに右辺値が入ります。

※実際はもっと細かい処理がありますが、よくあるバターン以外は省略しています。

valueやwritableは`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`で確認できます。通常のメソッドはvalueが関数でwritableが真になっているプロパティです。セットにおいても、プロトタイプチェーンは辿ります。コンストラクター関数(クラスのこと)のprototypeでプロパティが見つかっても、書き込み不可やセッターの確認をするだけで、そのプロパティに対して右辺値を入れるのではありません。プロパティとして作成されるのは、いつもレシーバーに対して行われることになります。

このように、書き込み不可フラグやセッターの話も含めると、プロパティのセットは常にレシーバー自身がもつプロパティに対して行っているという単純な話ではありません。ただ、プロトタイプチェーンを辿った結果、それが普通の値(メソッドを含む)だったり、見つからなかったときは、レシーバー自身が持つプロパティに対して処理が行われることになります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
引っかかっていた部分の解釈が間違っていなかったみたいで安心しました。
細かい話の部分も詳しく書いていただいてとても参考になります。
今の自分では分からないことが多いのですが、後で時間をかけて読んでみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

javascript はよく知らない自分がレスするのも恐縮ですが・・・

質問にあったコード:

```js
class Fuga {
  bar = 'これはプロパティ';
  bar() {
    console.log('これはメソッド');
  }
}
```

は有効なのでしょうか？　自分の環境 Windows 10 の Chrome 122.0.6261.112 で試すと bar() の方は無視（？）されるようです。

関数 bar を以下のように変更すると上書きされます。

```js
bar = () => {
    console.log('これはメソッド');
}
```

そのあたりの違いで、期待と違う結果になっているということはありませんか？

自分の環境で検証に使ったコードと結果を参考に以下に書いておきます。

```js
class Hoge {
    foo() {
        console.log('元の foo');
    }
}
const hoge = new Hoge();

hoge.foo();

console.log('-------------------------');

class Fuga {
    bar = 'これはプロパティ';
    bar() {
        console.log('これはメソッド');
    }
}

const fuga = new Fuga();

for (var key in fuga) {
    console.log(key + ':' + fuga[key]);
}

// fuga.bar(); => Uncaught TypeError: fuga.bar is not a function

console.log('-------------------------');

class Fuga2 {
    bar = 'これはプロパティ';
    bar= () => {
        console.log('これはメソッド');
    }
}

const fuga2 = new Fuga2();

for (var key in fuga2) {
    console.log(key + ':' + fuga2[key]);
}

fuga2.bar();
```

結果は:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。質問の仕方が良くなかったかもしれません…
`Fuga`の部分はややこしくなりそうなので、質問を編集させていただきました。